# Why do we need to pop Hash to create this calculate method?

Tags: ruby, hash

```
def add(*numbers)
    numbers.inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }  
end

def subtract(*numbers)
  sum = numbers.shift
  numbers.inject(sum) { |sum, number| sum - number }  
end

def calculate(*arguments)
  # if the last argument is a Hash, extract it 
  # otherwise create an empty Hash
  options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
  options[:add] = true if options.empty?
  return add(*arguments) if options[:add]
  return subtract(*arguments) if options[:subtract]
end
```

Could someone explain to me in plain english why we need to check if the last argument in this code is a hash and then pop it  :

```
options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
```

Thanks

Comment: because it is poorly written. if it were written by someone who knows how to write code then you won't have this question because you would be able to understand what is going on by just reading the code. :)

Comment: @akonsu actually, that implementation is not that bad. Its very intuitive if you know the language. That implementation works perfectly for a undefined amount of arguments and an optional options hash. Otherwise the method would have to take an array of integers as the first parameter and then the options hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that code is implemented is by calling the calculate method with list of arguments. In that list, the last argument if it is a Hash it will be an options hash. Doing arguments.pop will extract the options hash from the argument list.

`calculate(1,2,3,{add: false, subtract: true})` will end up returning `subtract(1,2,3)`

doing

`calculate(1,2,3)` will end up calling `add(1,2,3)`

**UPDATE**

To answer your comment on the other answer, you need to pop it out of the `arguments` variable because of the way the `add` and `subtract` methods are implemented. If you notice these methods start shifting arguments or use inject on the arguments which would not make much sense if the last argument was a hash. That's the reason why it is popped out before sending the `arguments` variable to the other methods.

This implementation is an interesting way to go about it as it would allow any number of integer arguments to be passed in and a optional last `options hash`.

Usually you'll see methods defined like this

```
def testing(arg1, arg2, options={})
  # some manipulation of the args and options
end
```

but that way of handling it would require you to make a parameter for each argument you might want to pass into the method

Answer (score 4):

Evidently, this function accepts an optional "options" hash as an argument along with a list of integers. The options are provided at the end of the list of arguments. So the function has to check for it and, if the options hash is there, pop it and put it in the options variable.

Comment: Why do we need to pop it tho? Why do we have to pop it to execute the hash?     Is this common syntax for executing an optional hash in ruby?

Comment: Because if you don't then the options hash it will get fed as parameters to the adder or subtractor. That would be bad.

Comment: And, yes, optional hashes are quite common in Ruby implementations, such as Rails, although they aren't always implemented quite the same way as in that example.